# Can Aerial Ace be dodged?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the Pokémon games, [Aerial Ace](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aerial_Ace_(move)) cannot be dodged.

Is this mechanic implemented? Can Aerial Ace be dodged in Pokémon GO?

Comment: Most of the mechanics from the original series are changed or completely ignored in Pokemon Go, so I would not use the original games as a guideline for how Pokemon Go should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to research done by The Silph Road community, the only move in the game that cannot be dodged is Blizzard. The rest of the moves are capable of being dodged.

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df-5-1D4ZrI)

Comment: If this is true, then having Blizzard on a defending Pokemon would be attractive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Aerial Ace can be dodged.  There are varying length dodge windows on special moves, and it is very difficult to dodge Aerial Ace, but not impossible.